# How to call an instance of a class without knowing the name beforehand

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

Say I have different instances of a class;

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id

Joe = Person('123')
Sarah = Person('321')
```

My question now is, how would I be able use one of the instances without knowing the name before hand, for example, I could have something that requests for a name or even id. How would I associate it with the appropriate object? Say an input of an id, '123' was given, how do I get to know that it belongs to the `Joe` object and then **use** that object dynamically? I am running Python 3.6 if that info is of much use.

Comment: There are ways, but this is serious code smell and sounds like poor design from the beginning. But the easiest way would be to keep your objects in a `dict` that maps `id` to the required `Person` object...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you study computer programming, you will probably hear a not-really-a-joke that there are only three important numbers: 0, 1, and infinity. In other words, you can have none of something or one of something, but if you can have more than one, you have to be prepared to handle any number of them.

When you can only have zero or one of something, putting it in a variable is fine. But this solution quickly becomes unwieldy when you can have any number of something. The solution favored by programmers is to put the objects in a *container,* like a list or dictionary.

For example, the dictionary approach:

```
people = {"123": Person("123"), "321": Person("321")}
```

Then Joe is `people["123"]`.

In reality you want to store the person's name in the object as well, otherwise you can't tell who it actually represents, so you'd add that to your `Person` class. You could also have the object add *itself* to the master people dict when it's instantiated:

```
people = {}

class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, id, name):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        people[id] = self

joe = Person("123", "Joe")
sarah = Person("321", "Sarah")
```

Now when you instantiate objects they are added to the `people` dict by their ID automatically, and you can access them as such. (You could also add them by name, assuming the names are unique: even to the same dictionary if IDs and names can never clash.)

N.B. "calling" has a specific meaning in programming: you call a function. You are not calling anything here.

Comment: One might consider making `people` a class variable.